# Rolling up Dependencies to Requests/PageViews in ApplicationInsights Analytics

Tags: azure-application-insights

Based on datapoint numbers I'm seeing, a client's website is averaging 28 dependencies per each request. That does seem very high to me so I'd like to do some analysis by rolling dependency data points up on page views and requests to the website. Unfortunately, looking at the fields available via Application Insights, there doesn't seem to be a natural field to join dependency to pageviews or requests. Any thoughts as to how I would go about doing so?

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using [OperationContext](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/master/src/Core/Managed/Shared/Extensibility/Implementation/OperationContext.cs)

Comment: Could you expand on your answer with a little more detail?  I'm quite familiar with AI, but maybe I'm not thinking clearly, but I'm not sure how you could flow an OperationContext through with a PageView?

Comment: This context exists on all telemetry items and can be used for correlation. But yes, you will have to do a manual work: in JS SDK assign some id to pageview, pass this id to your backend using cookies, headers or anything else, in Web SDK add telemetry initializes that reads this header and assign it to request telemetry/dependency telemetry. We pass user and session the same way, you can use it as an example since both repos are open source.

Comment: ah okay thank you very much that explanation made it clear to me!

Answer (score 1):

This may get you running in the right direction

```
requests
| where timestamp > ago(1d)
| project timestamp, operation_Id
| join (dependencies
        | where timestamp > ago(1d)
        | summarize count(duration) by operation_Id, type 
        ) on operation_Id
```

This is what I use to look at 22 hours of my data for a particular request talking to sql server

```
 // Requests
requests
| where timestamp >= datetime(2017-08-24T08:59:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2017-08-25T06:30:00.001Z)
| where (itemType == 'request' and ((timestamp >= datetime(2017-08-24T09:00:00.000Z) and timestamp <= datetime(2017-08-25T06:30:00.000Z)) and (client_Type == 'PC' and operation_Name == 'POST /CareDelivery/CareDelivery/ServiceUserDetailsForDeviceUserChunked/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')))
| join (dependencies
        | where timestamp >= datetime(2017-08-24T08:59:59.999Z) and timestamp < datetime(2017-08-25T06:30:00.001Z)
        | summarize count(duration) by operation_Id, type 
        ) on operation_Id
| summarize count_dependencies=avg(count_duration) by type, bin(timestamp, 20m)
```

Post this into the query and the format will be ok, and you can read it - wish I could